# Interface events pattern

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns

```
public interface IConnector
{
       void Connect();
       event EventHandler<EventArgs> Received;

      // and more
}

public class ConnectorA: IConnector
{
     public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Received;

     public void Connect(){
     ...
     }
}

public class ConnectorB: IConnector
{
       public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Received;

       public void Connect(){
       ...
       }
}
```

Now let's say I have a factory like this:

```
public interface IConnectorFactory
{
    void Create(string type);
}

public class ConnectorFactory: IConnectorFactory
{
    public void Create(string type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case "A":
                return new ConnectorA();
            case "B":
                return new ConnectorB();
        }
    }
}
```

I inject this factory via constructor to Manager class:

```
public class Manager
{
    IConnectorFactory _factory;
    IConnector _actualConnector;
    string _type;
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return _type;
        }

        set
        {
            _type = value;
            if (_actualConnector != null)
            {
                _actualConnector.Disconnect();
                _actualConnector.Received -= ReceivedFunc;
            }

            _actualConnector = _factory.Create(Type);
            _actualConnector.Received += ReceivedFunc;
        }
    }

    public Manager(IConnectorFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        _actualConnector.Connect();
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        _actualConnector.DoSomethingElse();
        _actualConnector.Received += ReceivedFunc;
    }

    public void ReceivedFunc()
    {
    }
}
```

Type is property that is set external (for example binded to UI ComboBox). Problem is that every time it is changed I have to unsubscribe old event and subscribe to new event. Isn't there some pattern for subscribing to interface event?

Comment: Btw: `EventHandler<EventArgs>` is just `EventHandler`.

Comment: Can you try and distill this example further, or highlight what you think is wrong? It is difficult to understand what the question is about

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to `_actualConnector`:

```
_actualConnector = _factory.Create(Type);
```

your're just changing a field and the old object has still its `Received` event handled by `ReceivedFunc`. This has nothing to do with interfaces, this is the way objects and references work in .NET

Comment: but look at this flow: Change to ConnectorA, then ConnectorB then ConnectorA, every time I receive new instance, so event is not subscribed and I have to assign new event and unsubscribe old event. I am asking is there any better way ?

Comment: Let's discuss your design. You want each instance of the `Manager` class have a reference to one instance of `IConnector` in `_actualConnector` field and handle this object's `Received` event. Am I right?

Comment: Pardon me the comments. I want to reach the best solution. Now let's see if it is possible to implementation the code to match your design. You want the `Manager` to be a wrapper for all `Connector`s and you don't want to create a new instance of `Manager` every time the connector is changed.